# Multi-device btrfs with single data mode and disk failure

Tags: data-recovery, btrfs

I had a btrfs partition on a 6 disk array without raid (metadata in raid10, but data in single), and one of the disks just died.

So I lost some of my data, ok, I knew that.

But two questions:

- Is it possible to know (using metadata I suppose) what data I have lost?
- Is it possible to do some kind of a "btrfs delete missing" on this kind of setup, in order to recover access in rw to my other data, or I must copy all my data on a new partition?

Edit : just to be clear, I can mount it in read only with `mount -o recovery,ro,degraded`

And btrfs fi df /Data

```
Data, single: total=6.65TiB, used=6.65TiB
System, RAID1: total=32.00MiB, used=768.00KiB
Metadata, RAID1: total=13.00GiB, used=10.99GiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=512.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

Comment: It's probably worth asking this on Server Fault instead http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Ok, i just did that, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a very very lucky guy, and I think I fixed my problem (thanks to the help of btrfs mailing list).

In my situation "btrfs-debug-tree -t 3 /dev/sda6" does not mention the missing disk anywhere (data or metadata). So there was nothing at all in the missing device.

Thus, patching the kernel with [this patch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/7014141/%20%22this%20patch) allow me to mount the array in rw in degraded and a simple `btrfs device remove missing` did the trick.

So my array is fixed and my data seems fine (scrub in progress)

One thing I learned though is that the single mode should never ever be used.

Comment: the link to the patch is wrong heres the correct one https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/7014141/